# Underline effect through styled components not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles, styled-components

I would like to make the effect of underlining links when hovering over styled components, for some reason hover is not working and not even after

```
export const Links = styled.div ` 

    ul {
        display: flex;
    }

    li {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 1.4vh;
        cursor: pointer;
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;

        &::after {
            content: "";
            width: 0;
            height: 4px;
            background-color: #ff914d;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        &:hover::after {
            width: 100%;
        }

    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are missed:

1. For nested selectors in styled components you can use this -

```css
 &:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

2. Since, pseudo selector ::after has position absolute, in order to get the underline effect, make

   as position relative.

here is the final output

```css
export const Links = styled.div ` 

    ul {
        display: flex;
    }

    li {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 1.4vh;
        cursor: pointer;
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
        position: relative;

        &::after {
            content: "";
            width: 0;
            height: 4px;
            background-color: #ff914d;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        &:hover:after {
            width: 100%;
        }

    }
`;
```